# Paginating with Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Having a little bit of trouble with Firebase's Firestore. I am trying to basically paginate a query, and start at the spot I last left off on.

I was trying to just pass the document in but was getting a JS error. So I am trying to do it with the timestamp. I can't figure out the exact syntax needed, and am unsure where specifically you are specifying the start at field

Is there a way to start at the key of the document?

```
.orderBy("timestamp").startAt(LastSeenTimestamp).limit(10)
```

Basically just passing in a string of the last timestamp, however doesn't seem to be working and ends up returning nothing

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the `LastSeenTimestamp` you're passing in of the same type that you write?  Can you try using a native JS `Date` object rather than a string (if you used ServerTimestamp to write the field).

Comment: so upon creating a new document on the server, I use "firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()" . I guess I could then parse into a Date() object when I pass Last Seen Timestamp

Comment: Yes try passing a Date object, that should give the result you're looking for.

Comment: Do you have any idea as to how you would parse that into a date object? I was looking at the api of the fieldvalue.servertimestamp and cant really figure it out

Comment: If `LastSeenTimestamp` is a string in the correct format just use `Date.parse()` to get a `Date` object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Comment: Ah, the issue its in some firebase class format..not a string

Comment: Not sure how to handle that